# Ruby on Rails - seed from development database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, development-environment, production-environment, seed

I have **deployed** my Application to my website now. In my `Development ENV`, I have a table called `cities` and contains 47K cities/records. How can I `seed` all of these cities to my `Production ENV`.

I am only thinking to do a one time `seed` and only for `cities` database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a gem such as https://github.com/rroblak/seed_dump to dump the selected table then on the production server run `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:seed` to seed the data.

`rake db:seed:dump MODELS=cities APPEND=true` looks like the command you need to run to dump the data out into a seed file.

Otherwise you could export the database table as a MySQL dump and import it into the production database.

Answer (score 0):

You said you only need to do this once in production but it is usually something that any other developer (or yourself in the future) may need to do it again so I would really turn this into a seed file or a CSV.

Here is how you could create a CSV and then import it in production.

```
require 'csv'
attributes = %w{name country}

CSV.open('cities.csv','w') do |csv|
    csv << attributes

    City.find_each do |city|
      csv << attributes.map{ |attr| city.send(attr) }
    end
  end
end
```